# Serialize List(Of Long)

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I have read like 2 GB of long values from text files into a List(Of Long) in VB.NET.

Because reading the values from the text files into the List(Of Long) is quite time-consuming, I wanted to serialize the List(Of Long), hoping that VB.NET would provide me a way to quickly deserialize it.

How could I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Serialize has some overhead and most probably will be slower. Your best bet might be to just use a stream. 2GB is a lot of data, is there a way to only load part of it (only what you need)?

Comment: @the_lotus  Thank you. I really need everything of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using XmlSerialization to store and retrieve the data.  Drop two buttons (btnSerialize, btnDeserialize) and a ProgressBar (ProgressBar1) on a Form.  This resulted in a 2.31 GB file on my system.  It does take awhile to process, thus the async code and the marquee progressbar.

Note that with such a large file, it would not deserialize the whole thing in one shot with `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` (I got an "out of memory" exception).  Instead, we have to read in the xml file record by record, which is more memory efficient:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public Class Form1

    Private FileName As String
    Private HugeListOfLongs As New List(Of Long)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim MyDocs As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(MyDocs, "LongData.xml")

        For L As Long = 0 To 100000000
            HugeListOfLongs.Add(L)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub btnSerialize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSerialize.Click
        btnSerialize.Enabled = False
        btnDeserialize.Enabled = False
        ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True

        Dim success As Boolean
        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                           Try
                               Dim xml As New XmlSerializer(HugeListOfLongs.GetType)
                               Using fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                                   fs.SetLength(0) ' make sure it's empty before we start writing (so you don't have trailing data if new file is smaller than previous one)
                                   xml.Serialize(fs, HugeListOfLongs)
                               End Using
                               success = True
                           Catch ex As Exception
                               MessageBox.Show("Failed to Serialize." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
                               success = False
                           End Try

                       End Sub)

        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        If success Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data successfully written to: " & vbCrLf & FileName)
        End If
        btnSerialize.Enabled = True
        btnDeserialize.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub btnDeserialize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeserialize.Click
        btnSerialize.Enabled = False
        btnDeserialize.Enabled = False
        ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True

        Dim success As Boolean
        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                           HugeListOfLongs.Clear()
                           Try
                               Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(FileName)
                               While Not reader.EOF
                                   If reader.Read Then
                                       If reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text Then
                                           HugeListOfLongs.Add(Long.Parse(reader.Value))
                                       End If
                                   End If
                               End While
                               reader.Close()
                               success = True
                           Catch ex As Exception
                               MessageBox.Show("Failed to Deserialize." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
                               success = False
                           End Try
                       End Sub)

        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        If success Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data successfully read from: " & vbCrLf & FileName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Number of Longs: " & HugeListOfLongs.Count)
        End If
        btnSerialize.Enabled = True
        btnDeserialize.Enabled = True
    End Sub

End Class
```